# MasterDetail navigation using prism

Tags: xamarin.forms

I recently started building a Xamarin Forms application using Prism.

I'm not able to navigate with the MasterDetail Navigation. The button I use to navigate seems to not make the binding correctly. I never been able to reach the executed command with a breakpoint when clicking on the button.
Everything except the command binding seems to do the binding correctly, so I really have no idea on what is going on.

I already checked out the GitHub sample made available by the Prism team (HamburgerMenu project). I'm convince to use the exact same configuration as the sample but no way to make it works on my project.

Bellow is the code used currently:

MainPage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MonkeyVault.Views.MainPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <NavigationPage Title="Required Foo" Icon="ic_menu.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu">
                    <StackLayout Padding="40">
                        <Label Text="{Binding UserName, StringFormat='Hello, {0}'}"/>
                        <Button Text="Sites" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Navigation/Sites" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            #region Fields

            private string _userName;

            #endregion

            #region Properties

            public string UserName
            {
                get => _userName;
                set => SetProperty(ref _userName, value);
            }

            public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand;

            public DelegateCommand NCommand;

            #endregion

            public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
                : base(navigationService)
            {
                Title = "Main Page";

                NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnNavigateCommandExecuted);
            }

            private async void OnNavigateCommandExecuted(string path)
            {
                await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(path);
            }
        }
```

If someone has already encountered this problem or has any idea I would be greatful.

Comment: Not that I am too familiar with Prism, but how is the BIndingContext with the MasterDetailPage made. In a MasterDetailPage, both the master and detail section should have their BIndingContext set to the appropriate ViewModel.

Comment: @AdamPedley This view is wired to the view model automatically via naming conventions allowing for databinding to the view model. It works, the binding on the 'UserName' property is working as intented, only the command binding is not triggered and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your DelegateCommand as a Property.

```
public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }
```

Admittedly I am just guessing here, but I have had problems binding to Fields before and needed to change it to a property to get binding.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I really do not understand why, but it works just well. You make my day!

Comment: While I haven't delved into the BindingEngine in Xamarin, since would have to use Reflection to get properties to bind to, it would be using methods like GetRuntimeProperty etc. These will only get properties, as you have to use different methods to get fields.

Comment: Thanks to provide a detailed answer. As usual you seems to be well informed. By the way, I recently had the good fortune of reading your articles regarding Xamarin forms in https://xamarinhelp.com/. It is well-written and contains so much pratical good advices. I look forward to reading your next article. Please keep doing such a good work :)